# Add Header View to UICollectionView

Tags: xamarin

I am struggling with binding of a header to UICollectionView. I have done a lot of research but could not find anything effective. I am not setting any layout programmatically . RegisterClassForSupplementaryView is not working also. Do I need to add layout Programmatically?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit? Its not clear now what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I need to add a header view in UIcollectionView.  have setsupplementary view for this. But its not working.

Comment: Try to add layout programmatically which can be easily done. Give header reference in layout.

Comment: @Manish I have already resolved this one. Thanks anyway :)